NextJs + googleapis(Patch function), moving folder/file to a designated folder
I'm trying to create a Patch feature using nextjs + googleapis to move specific files/folders to another Folder
this is the code I'm trying it out with :
const moveFileOrFolder = async () => {
  if (!session || !selectedItemId || !destinationFolderId) return;

  try {
    const auth = `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`;
   
    // Fetch the current parents of the selected item
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${selectedItemId}?fields=id,name,parents`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: auth,
        },
      }
    );
    console.log("Response" , selectedItemId)
    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();

      // Prepare the current parents
      const currentParents = data.parents || [];

      // Check if the destination folder is already a parent
      if (currentParents.includes(destinationFolderId)) {
        console.error("The destination folder is already a parent of the selected item.");
        return;
      } 
      
      // Prepare the request to move the file/folder
      const updateResponse = await fetch(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${destinationFolderId}?fields=id,name`,
        {
          method: "PATCH",
          headers: {
            Authorization: auth,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ 
          addParents: destinationFolderId, // Specify the new parent
          removeParents: currentParents.join(','), // Specify the current parents to remove
          }), 
        }
      );
       console.log("Update Response" , destinationFolderId)
      if (updateResponse.ok) {
        console.log("File/Folder moved successfully!" , updateResponse);
      } else {
        const errorData = await updateResponse.json();
        console.error("Error moving file/folder:", updateResponse.status, errorData);
      }
    } else {
      const errorData = await response.json();
      console.error("Error fetching file/folder details:", response.status, errorData);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error moving file/folder:", error);
  }
};

on the Body upon checking or error handling it, it gave me a message asking for addParent & removeParent, i have added it, and im able to get a message that the File?Folder have been moved, but upon checking on my google drive there are no folders that was moved. I have also checked my Api routes (added a scopes for the Patch ).
If anyone can help me understand as to how to make it work and why its showing the message but no changes, that would be much appreciated

i got it fixed, i just didnt understand/knew the google docs on the path parameters and query parameters , so what I have been trying to use the addParent and removeParent inside a body request , but it should have been inside the Path parameters instead.
So its all working good now

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
